# Many small models vs. one big model

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am currently implementing kind of a questionnaire with a chatbot and use LUIS to interpret the answers. This questionnaire is divided into segments of maybe 20 questions.

Now the following question came to mind: Which option is better?

1. I make one LUIS model per question. Since these questions can include implicit subquestions (i.e. "Do you want to pay all at once or in rates" could include a "How high should these rates be?") I end up with maybe 3-5 intents per question (including `None`).
2. I can make one model per segment. Let's assume that this is possible and fits in the 80 intents per model.

My first intuition was to think that the first alternative is better since this should be way more robust. When there are only 5 intents to choose from, then it may be easier to determine the right one. As far as I know, there is no restriction in how many models you can have (...is this correct?).

So here is my question for SO: What other benefits/drawbacks are there and is there maybe an option that is objectively the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many models as you want, there is no limit on this. But onto the rest of your question:

You intend to use LUIS to interpret every response? I'm curious as to the actual design of the questionnaire and why you need (or want) open ended responses and not multiple-choice questions. `"Do you want to pay all at once or in rates"` itself is a binary question. Branching off of this, users might respond with, `"Yes I want to pay all at once"`, which could use LUIS. Or they could respond with, `"rates"` which could be one of two choices available to the user in a Prompt/FormFlow. `"rates"` is also much shorter than the first answer and thus a selection that would probably be typed more often than not.

Multiple-choice questions provide a standardized input which would reduce the amount of work you'd have to do in managing your data. It also would most likely reduce the amount of effort needed to maintain the models and questionnaire.

Objectively speaking, one model is more likely to be less work, but we can drill down a little further:

---

#### First option:

If your questionnaire segments include 20 questions and you have 2 segments, you have 40 individual models to maintain which is a nightmare.
Additionally, you might experience latency issues depending on your recognizer order, because you have to wait for a response from **40 endpoints**. This said it IS possible to turn off recognizers so you might only need to wait for one recognizer. But then you need to manually turn on the next recognizer and turn off the previous one. You should also be aware that handling multiple "None" intents is a nightmare, in case you wish to leave every recognizer active.

I'm assuming that you'll want assistance in managing you models after you realize the pain of handling forty of them by yourself. You can add collaborators, but then you need to add them to multiple models as well. One day you'll (probably) have to remove them from all of the models they have collaborator status on.

The first option IS more robust but also involves a rather extreme amount of work hours. You're partially right in that fewer intents is helpful because of fewer possibilities for the model to predict. But the predictions of your models become more accurate with more utterances and labeling, so any bonus gained by having 5 intents per model is most likely to be rendered moot.

---

#### Second option:

Using one model per segment, as mentioned above is less work. It's less work to maintain, but what are some downsides? Until you train your model well enough, there may indeed be some unintended consequences due to false-positive predictions. That said, you could account for that in your questionnaire/bot/questionnaire-bot's code to specifically look for the expected intents for the question and then use the highest scoring intent from this subset if the highest scoring intent overall doesn't match to your question.

Another downfall is that if it's one model and a collaborator makes a catastrophic mistake, it affects the entire segment. With multiple models, the mistake would only affect the one question/model, so that's a plus.

Aside from not having to deal with multiple None-intent handling, you can quickly label utterances that *should* belong to the None intent. What you label as an intent in a singular model essentially makes it stand out more against the other intents inside of the model. If you have multiple models, an answer that triggers a specific intent in one model needs to trigger the None intent in your other models, otherwise, you'll end up with multiple high scoring intents (and the relevant/expected intents might not be the highest scoring).

---

#### End:

I recommend the second object, simply because it's less work. Also, I'm not sure of the questionnaire's goals, but as a general rule, I question the need of putting in AI where it's not needed. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-design-principles#factors-that-do-not-guarantee-a-bots-success) is a link that talks about factors that do *not* contribute to a bot's success (note that Natural Language is one of these factors).

Comment: First of all: thanks for the answer, it was very helpful. The problem with several endpoints and `None` intents are solved by only sending data to the model of the current question. I agree with you, that a using Prompt/FormFlow would be a more accurate, robust and in general better way, but this is more of an explorative project to see what we can do with these tools.

Comment: Understood :) If you're the blogging type, I'd be happy to read what your experiences are on whichever path you choose to follow. I think it would be a good story to share with the community, and we don't get a lot of questions regarding LUIS-questionnaires or surveys.